# Deleting/"Rebasing" rails migrations

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, git-rebase

I've been working in a git branch on one portion of a rails site. I've made a lot of random changes to the schema while iterating, and I've made some migrations that revert previous migrations to add columns and things like that. Is it OK to delete redundant migrations like those (i.e. pairs of migrations that are just reverses of each other)? I don't see why it would cause any problems because no one else is working on this branch, and the end result will be the same. Is there any chance of trouble if I go ahead with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There *should* be no problems, assuming you know perfectly good what to do and how to do it.

*But*, you should ask yourself why you want to do this? It is no addition to your project. It only masks (some of) your iterations, which might be convenient to look back later to understand your working process or to explain it to someone else.

Personally, I would just merge your branch with the main branch without deleting any changes at all. Nothing to be ashamed of right?

Comment: You have VCS to keep history of changes. The reason to delete is to keep current version simple.

Comment: To add to what @Alexey said, it is helpful to decrease migration time