# Aggregate migrations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, migration

I have several dozens Rails DB migrations which were written over a year. Is there a way to aggregate them to one migration so that I will just see a full DDL statement for the database as it exists now? I just need the current snaphot without all the history of how we got to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, but **probably not a good idea** to aggregate the migrations!

Maybe ask:

- Why do you want to do this?
- How often do you really need to migrate all the way to VERSION=0 and then back up again?
- Is something really broken?  (if not, then don't fix it)

I've had the same problem once.. I ended up just re-ordering my migrations, because changes in the schema caused it to not correctly migrate up/down anymore. I would be hesitant to do that again.

If you have migrations which just add fields or indexes, then maybe you can combine them with the main migration for the model -- but **beware that you can't reproduce old situations anymore, e.g. older DB-dumps may not be compatible with what migration number they should be compatible with** -- that is probably the biggest argument against aggregating...

Technically, you can dump the schema and then load it directly - that is one way:

```
rake db:schema:dump
```

then create a single new migration with the contents of the schema dump file db/schema.rb

Here are some similar questions:

- [Rebase Rails migrations in a long running project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343534/rebase-rails-migrations-in-a-long-running-project)
- [Deleting/"Rebasing" rails migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253788/deleting-rebasing-rails-migrations)
- [Way to "flatten" Rails migrations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271655/way-to-flatten-rails-migrations)
- [Should I flatten Rails migrations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910001/should-i-flatten-rails-migrations)

---

P.S.: I found it useful to stick with the old migration numbering scheme, where the migrations do not use timestamps - for me this works better (is easier to see in which order they are).

e.g. in your config/application.rb file:

```
config.active_record.timestamped_migrations = false
```

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer. The immediate reason why I wanted it, was just to be able to conveniently see the DB schema. Since Rails prefers to do many ususal RDBMS tasks itself (e.g., referential integrity, constraints), I would like to see them in one place.

Comment: `rake db:schema:dump` is what i needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply load the current schema into the DB.

`rake db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=[production, test, etc.]`

This will take the `schema.rb` file's version of the schema, and load it into the DB without running individual migrations.

NOTE: if you have migrations that put data into the DB (e.g. default values, for example), that data will not be added to the DB.

If you need to load default values into your DB, that might be better done via a custom rake task, independent of migrations.

Answer (score 2):

You should never be using all the migrations to get a database up and running.  The current schema.rb is always what the DB looks like 'presently'.

It's good practice to periodically just truncate your migrations if you have a ton of them in there.  We finally did that with one of our larger applications, removing a good 50 migrations from the folder because the only thing that matters is schema.rb.  Migrations are just that, a way to *migrate* and make changes to an existing state of the database.  They should only ever have to be run once.